# why don't I get error messages in admin when developing?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, errors

I am curious as to why my screen goes completely blank when an error is present in my code. This only happens to me when it is an admin function.

No warnings, no syntax error messages, nothing. Just a blank screen. Which makes it really difficult to find the problem.

How do I get the errors to show up and how do I stop the blank screen?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
// Enable debugging
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Comment: cool thanx! What's the reason for adding the constant instead of having it on by default? Just curious.

Comment: Having it on by default? Have you **seen** the output generated by most Plugins?

Comment: Turned it on and holy crap! Now I need to fix 5+ plugins code or re-write them. At least mine only had the one error. This makes me kind of wish there was a standard that plugins have to follow or they cannot be installed/used. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Never mind plugins, I've just switched it on and WP 3.3 generates quite a few messages itself.